# How to Start same activity with different data from Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-lifecycle

I have 1 activity that I would like to start at different times with different variables from a Broadcast Receiver.

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("tv.abcd.v4.ORIGINAL_VIDEO_SCENE")){
                channelName = intent.getExtras().getString("com.abcd.Channel");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.abcd.Data"));
            String incomingScene = json.getString("url");
            scene.putExtra("channel", channelName);
            scene.putExtra("url", incomingScene);
            scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
            scene.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            context.startActivity(scene);

  }
```

I have the code to start the activity via Intent and in the activity receiver the extras to make data appear.

```
            Intent intent = getIntent();
sceneUrl = intent.getStringExtra("url");
Log.d("Image.incomingscene.url",sceneUrl);
channelName = intent.getStringExtra("channel");
Log.d("Image.incomingSceneAvatar",networkAvatar);
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
Picasso.with(this).load(sceneUrl).skipMemoryCache().fit().into(image, new EmptyCallback() {

});
```

Now after that I want to start the same activity again from the Broadcast Reciever with different data. So i want the previous activity to get out the way and allow this new instance to start up.

How to accomplish this feat?

Comment: please post your code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

register another broadcast receiver from the activity. Then, when you want to kill it, send a broadcast message from the broadcast receiver that you mentioned .

In your broadcastReceiver do something like the following :

```
  public static final String CLOSE_Activity= "com.mypackage.closeactivity";
```

and in yopr OnReceive method do like the following :

```
@Override   
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
       System.out.println("HIT OUTGOING");      
   Intent i = new Intent();      
   i.setAction(CLOSE_Activity);       
  context.sendBroadcast(i);    
 }
```

then in your activity craete a receviver and register it in the onResume method and unregeister it in the onPause method , like the following :

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVER_Class.CLOSE_Activity)) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

activity onResume method :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(RECEIVER_Class.CLOSE_Activity));
}
```

activity onPause method :

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

Please give me some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: thats sounds genius! gimmie some time to implement brb

Comment: EXCELLENT! only thing is it doesnt stop, it still going right now, it keep broadcasting... I see endless syslog message HIT OUTGOING. also, how do i stop it and then immediately start it back up with new data....

Comment: I had force stop the app in order to stop the CLOSE broadcast from repeatedly sending...

Comment: in your Braodcast that is opening the activity :
first send broadcast to close the already opened activity 
second : start the activity with the new data .

Comment: when i try to open the activity from the broadcast reciever it immediately closes, because the CLOSE broadcast is still sending...how do i stop the CLOSE broadcast after it has closed the activity. it just keeps going

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46205/discussion-between-sirvon-and-amrola)